# Como o strtoull funciona?

Tags: c, c++

Já tentei de todo jeito entender o que é o segundo parametro pra usar essa função e ela em geral mas ainda não consegui entender.

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro parâmetro da strtoull é a string a ser convertida.

O terceiro parâmetro é a base numérica. Para números escritos em decimal é 10, para hexadecimal é 16, etc.

O segundo parâmetro tem a ver com o fato de o strtoull ignorar caracteres "inválidos" que estão fora da base que você escolheu. Por exemplo, `strtoull("123qwer456", NULL, 10)` retorna `123` e ignora o `"qwer456"`.

Se você quiser ignorar o "resto" depois da parte numérica, passe NULL como o segundo parâmetro. Se você quiser saber se há caracteres não-numéricos no final da string passe o endereço de um `char *` como segundo parâmetro.

```
char *resto;
unsigned long long n = strtoull("123qwer456", &resto, 10);
printf("O número é %ull, o resto da string é %s\n", n, resto);
```

Se a string passada pro strtoll conter apenas inteiros, "resto" vai ficar valendo uma string vazia (isso é, `*resto == '\0'`). Caso contrário, resto passa a apontar para o primeiro caractere inválido da string.

---

Mudando de assunto, se você tiver dúvida da documentação um bom lugar pra olhar é no [sito do Opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). E se você por acaso estiver no Linux a documentação já está instalada no seu computador, basta fazer um `man strtoull`.